# How do you play these chords?

Tags: piano

[image]

I've just learned about arpeggiated chords and I'm a little confused about them.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the lowest, and play them sequentially up to the highest. Pedal if needed as sometimes you can't hang on to the lowest notes. Start playing the lowest on the appropriate beat. Sometimes it can sound better if you start just before, and end up on the beat with the highest note, but it will depend on which style or period of music it is. How fast? Well, it depends on the tempo, and of course, all notes need to be played before the next notes arrive!

Comment: so do I have to play each note separately (i.e play the five notes, one after the other)?

Comment: Yes, roll them one after the other, bottom to top, similarly to a slow strum on a guitar.